# How to obtain app screenshots for different iphone sizes (4S, 5, 6) in XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, screenshot, dimensions

If I would like a certain screenshot to be displayed for all iphone screen size dimensions, how would I do this through the Xcode simulator?  For example, when I select the simulator to run on the iphone 6 and hit cmd+s, a screenshot is saved but only for the iphone 6 dimensions.  If I would like this same screenshot to be obtained for iphone 5 and iphone 4s, how would I do this?  This app can also run in the simulator for iphone 5 and 4s but the same exact screenshot cannot be replicated for obvious reasons.

Apple requires different screenshot sizes for app submission and I would like the screenshots to be the same across the board.

Comment: That's impossible. You have to obey Apple's instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run your app over each time for each simulated (or real) device and capture each screenshot separately.